# Java - String input error with allowance for extra inputs

Tags: java, string, input

I wanting to make an if statement where the user has to enter a 16 digit string and if they fail they have to try again. I've done this in c++ before but don't know how to do so in java. This is my code so far. I also want the card number to be saved in this format "xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" like a card number. should I just return it in that format?

```
public PersonalAccount(String user_firstName, String user_lastName, String user_accountNumber, String street, String town, String postcode, String user_cardNumber, char user_cardType) {  
    super(user_firstName, user_lastName, user_accountNumber, street, town, postcode);

    if (user_cardNumber.length() == 16) {    
        cardNumber = user_cardNumber; 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect card number length");
    }

    cardType = user_cardType;
}
```

Comment: all your shared code is doing is checking for the length constraint. Nothing other than that from your demand list.

Comment: Yeah i want it to check the length of card number is 16 and if it isn't it should make the user re-input

Comment: This code is a mess. What's the superclass? How does user interact with this code? Is it through some `Scanner` class? Then you may think of some kind of `while` loop. Hard to guess looking at what you provided.

Comment: FWIW, in Java, it's convention to name your variables in camel case starting with a lowercase letter: `userFirstName`, `userLastName`..etc. [Code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: The superclass is quite big to post, it creates an account with the details shown above (first name, last name etc). i'm using a software called bluej to input so no scanner.

Comment: @TommyO ok I'll change that thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should throw an exception (EG `IllegalArgumentException`) instead of printing error message to the console...

This way the caller could catch the exception, and act upon it.

As for the format, if you want to format the string, that is without spaces, to have spaces after each four digits, you should try something like this:

```
public String formatCardNumber(String cardNumber)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20);
   for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i+=4)
   {
      sb.append(' ').append(user_cardNumber, i, i + 4);
   }
   return sb.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: is this even related to the question? and an answer even?

Comment: OP wants re-input values if not correct. This is a constructor. So the obvious solution to throw an exception, and handle the exception in the caller of the constructor, EG re input the values not correct...

Comment: How would this work in code? and how would this allow the user to re-input.

Comment: I've just put it in and it worked by causing and error and not allowing the code from being created. I think I might just leave it at that. Any clue on the format part of my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this to

1. check if 16 digits were entered
2. throw an Exception to indicate that the input is incorrect
3. return the values with spaces after ever every forth digit if the format is correct.

   ```
   String checkCardnumber(String user_cardNumber) {
     if(!user_cardNumber.matches("[\\d]{16}")) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     } else {
       return user_cardNumber.replaceAll("([\\d]{4})([\\d]{4})([\\d]{4})([\\d]{4})", "$1 $2 $3 $4");
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I wanting to save it into CardNumber in this format though, is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by save? You can store it in any String.